# Execute function of another class in kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Going straight to the point: I would like to click on the MDFilRoundFlatButton button in the ContentButton class and execute the close_order function in the TelaClose class

Can anyone help me on this one?

I'm still a little confused about executing functions from other classes, especially with kivy.

I've come a long way in this matter, I could use root.get_screen(... but I get an error saying that my class doesn't have the object to be executed.

```
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRoundFlatIconButton
from kivymd.color_definitions import colors
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFillRoundFlatButton, MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.font_definitions import theme_font_styles
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
import json
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd import images_path
from kivymd.uix.expansionpanel import MDExpansionPanel, MDExpansionPanelOneLine

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

from kivymd.uix.list import (
    ImageLeftWidget,
    ThreeLineIconListItem,
    OneLineListItem,
)

# Imports para trabalhar com Firebase
from config import config
import pyrebase
import requests
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

today = date.today()
today_now = datetime.now()

Builder.load_string("""
<Content>
    adaptive_height: True
    orientation: 'vertical'

#    TwoLineIconListItem:
#        text: "(050)-123-45-67"
#        secondary_text: "Mobile"
#
#        IconLeftWidget:
#            icon: 'phone'


<ContentButton>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    adaptive_height: True

    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        size_hint: .9, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        text: "Fechar Pedido"
        on_release: root.fechar_pedido()


<TelaFechamento>:
    name: 'tela_fechamento'   

    ScrollView:
        pos_hint: {"top": .89}

        MDGridLayout:
            id: box
            cols: 1
            adaptive_height: True

""")


class InvoicePanel(MDExpansionPanel):
    pass


class Content(MDBoxLayout):
    '''Custom content.'''

class ContentButton(MDBoxLayout):
    '''Custom content.'''

# Classe criada para permitir alinhamento
class OneLineListItemAligned(OneLineListItem):
    def __init__(self, halign, **kwargs):
        super(OneLineListItemAligned, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids._lbl_primary.halign = halign


class TelaFechamento(Screen):

    def fechar_pedido(self):
        # Inicializando o banco de dados.
        firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
        db = firebase.database()

        app = MDApp.get_running_app()

        user_profiles = db.child('UserProfile').child(str(app.logged_user)).get(
            token=app.USER_MASTER)

        idpedido = {}

        # Preenchendo os dados das listas
        for produto in user_profiles.each():
            if 'Cart' in produto.key():

                items = produto.val().get('Cart')

                for k, v in items['Opened'].items():
                    idpedido[k] = v

                chave = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f")

                #print(json.dumps(id_pedido, indent=4))

        # ********************************************************************************************************************************
                # Criar pedidos importados no WShop
                db.child('UserProfile').child(str(app.logged_user)).child(produto.key()).child('Confirmed').child(
                    chave).set(idpedido, token=app.USER_MASTER)
                # Aqui abaixo devo criar o código para excluir de Cart
                # Code here, Code here, Code here, .....

    def pedidos_abertos(self):
        # Inicializando o banco de dados.
        firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
        db = firebase.database()

        app = MDApp.get_running_app()

        json_data = db.child('UserProfile').child(str(app.logged_user)).get(
            token=app.USER_MASTER)

        for produtos in json_data.each():
            #print(json.dumps(produtos.key(), indent=4))
            if produtos.key() == 'Cart':
                cart = produtos
                try:
                    openeds = cart.val()['Opened']

                    #print(json.dumps(openeds, indent=4), '...............')
                    # adicionar fatura como item principal
                    cw = Content()  # preencha o conteúdo à medida que os dados são analisados
                    ep = InvoicePanel(icon="./images/pedidos/shopping-cart.png", panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelOneLine(text=f'Produtos no carrinho:'),
                                    content=cw)

                    self.ids.box.add_widget(ep)

                    # -----------------------------------------------------
                    # Cria o Widget Especificamente para fechar o pedido.

                    # close_items = MDRaisedButton(
                    # text="[color=ffffff]FATURAR ESTES ITENS[/color]", size_hint=(.9, .9))
                    # cw.add_widget(close_items)

                    close_items = OneLineListItemAligned(
                        text='Fechar este pedido agora?',
                        md_bg_color=app.theme_cls.primary_dark,
                        halign="center", font_style="H6", on_press=self.fechar_pedido)

                    # close_items.bind(on_release=print("----------Click!"))
                    cw.add_widget(close_items)
                    # -----------------------------------------------------
                    cw.add_widget(ContentButton())
                    for key_item, value_item in openeds.items():
                        #print(json.dumps(key_item, indent=4), '************* key_item')

                        # Cria a imagem que será usada no TwoLineIconListItem.
                        image = ImageLeftWidget(
                            source=value_item['url']
                        )

                        # Cria o Widget conforme sua escolha.
                        items = ThreeLineIconListItem(text=value_item['product_code'],
                                                    secondary_text=value_item['product_description'],
                                                    tertiary_text='{} x R${} = R${}'.format(value_item['quantidade'], value_item['price'], value_item['total_item']), md_bg_color=get_color_from_hex('#FFFDE7'))
                        # Adiciona a imagem ao Widget acima.
                        items.add_widget(image)
                        cw.add_widget(items)
                except:
                    print('Ainda não possui pedidos!')

    def pedidos_faturados(self):
        # Inicializando o banco de dados.
        firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
        db = firebase.database()

        app = MDApp.get_running_app()

        json_data = db.child('UserProfile').child(str(app.logged_user)).get(
            token=app.USER_MASTER)

        for produtos in json_data.each():
            #print(json.dumps(produtos.key(), indent=4))
            if produtos.key() == 'Cart':
                cart = produtos
                try:
                    invoices = cart.val()['Invoice']
                    for key_invoice, value_invoice in invoices.items():

                        #print(json.dumps(value_invoice, indent=4))
                        # adicionar fatura como item principal
                        cw = Content()  # preencha o conteúdo à medida que os dados são analisados
                        ep = InvoicePanel(icon='./images/pedidos/invoice.png', panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelOneLine(text=f'Confirmado: {key_invoice}'),
                                        content=cw)

                        self.ids.box.add_widget(ep)

                        for key_item, value_item in value_invoice.items():
                            #print(json.dumps(key_item, indent=4))

                            # Cria a imagem que será usada no TwoLineIconListItem.
                            image = ImageLeftWidget(
                                source=value_item['url']
                            )

                            # Cria o Widget conforme sua escolha.
                            items = ThreeLineIconListItem(text=value_item['product_code'],
                                                        secondary_text=value_item['product_description'],
                                                        tertiary_text='{} x R${} = R${}'.format(value_item['quantidade'], value_item['price'], value_item['total_item']))
                            # Adiciona a imagem ao Widget acima.
                            items.add_widget(image)
                            cw.add_widget(items)
                except:
                    print('Ainda não possui pedidos!')

    def on_enter(self):
        self.pedidos_abertos()
        self.pedidos_faturados()

    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        app = MDApp.get_running_app()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the best approach to this.
We must start from the app and go navigating until we reach the window where the class is and after finding execute the function.

```
<ContentButton>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    adaptive_height: True

    MDFillRoundFlatButton:
        size_hint: .9, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        text: "Fechar Pedido"
        on_release: print(app.root.get_screen('main_screen').ids.screen_manager.get_screen('tela_fechamento').fechar_pedido())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).